# Only click Checkbox in clickable Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to design a layout with a checkbox inside of a relative layout. The relative layout is clickable and works as it is supposed to, but when the checkbox is click, it runs the checkbox code, and the relative view code.

Is there anyway to ignore the relative layout's `OnClickListener` while running the checkbox?

```
RelativeLayout holder = new RelativeLayout(context);
contactHolder.setId(View.generateViewId());

TextView name = new TextView(context);
final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);

checkBox.setId(View.generateViewId());

name.setText(contact.getName());
name.setId(View.generateViewId());

holder.addView(name);
holder.addView(checkBox);

checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!checkBox.isChecked()) {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }
            else if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });

holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!checkBox.isChecked()) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (checkBox.isChecked()){
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
userView.addView(holder);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the layout code? It doesn't seem like a very good idea to put the listener on the relative layout. There is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @WillEvers I want the whole area of the Relative Layout to be clickable, which is why I set up an `OnClickListener` there, and it works, except for the double toggle on checkBox click

Answer (score 0):

use this in Relativelayout

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: The Relative layout is already clickable, so no problems there. The checkbox and relative view are both clicked when I hit the check box, so it toggles the checkbox twice in a single click.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the listener from the check box. Then change the logic in RelativeLayout's listener to act based on the state of the check box.

Comment: I tried that today. Results were interesting. The Checkbox worked correctly if I clicked the relative layout, but if I clicked the checkbox itself, the underlying code of the relative layout listener didn't seem to trigger. How is it that now it doesn't trigger at all?

Comment: your code is incorrect, post it and maybe I can help